# React Native Init Command Generating Typescript Project

Tags: create-react-app, native-base, create-react-native-app

It feels like a basic question but whenever I am trying to create a react native project using the command provided [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) It is always creating a typescript project for me instead of blank javascript project. How do I force it to create a blank javascript project what I am doing wrong?

Here is screenshot of App.js of the project that is being created
[image: The type Node I am guessing is of typescript I am not sure I am not very good in typescript]

I have also tried making a project using native-base blank template but it is throwing an error

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template @native-base/react-native-template
```

Comment: Try this command for create project `npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

Answer (score 0):

React Native defaults new applications to TypeScript, but JavaScript may still be used. Files with a .jsx extension are treated as JavaScript instead of TypeScript, and will not be typechecked. JavaScript modules may still be imported by TypeScript modules, along with the reverse.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript